# Нужно определить число полученное выписыванием в обратном порядке цифр заданного трехзначного числа

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Нужно определить число полученное выписыванием в обратном порядке цифр заданного трехзначного числа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <clocale>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(866);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(866);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    int val = 0;
    int res = 0;
    cin >> val;
    cin >> res;

    cout << "Определить число: " << endl;
    cout << "Ввести трехзначное число: " << endl;
    cout << "for( ; val; res = res*10 + val%10, val /= 10)" << endl;


    cin.sync();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да не надо за меня решать я впервые на этом форуме.

Comment: потрудитесь сформулировать грамотно и корректно вопрос и не забудьте рассказать, что вы делали для решения задачи. Это ваше "Хорошо, нужна формула палиндрома" корректным вопросом не является. Имейте уважение к тем, чьей помощи просите

Comment: Вас понял.

Comment: так конкретно что не получается? Элементарно же - берете последнюю цифру, умножаете на 100, складываете с предпоследней, умноженной на десять, затем прибавляете первую цифру. Можно даже без цикла обойтись при желании

Comment: Вообще не понял к чему приведут эти действия.
Не знаю как все это дело корректно записать.

Comment: >Вообще не понял к чему приведут эти действия

это печально, что вы не понимаете столь простых вещей. Объясню подробнее. Допустим, есть число 456. Берете 3-ю цифру (это 6) и умножаете на 100. Получаете 600. Затем берете вторую цифру (это 5) и умножаете на 10, получится 50. Складываете. 600 + 50 = 650. Затем берете первую цифру (4) и прибавляете к полученной сумме 650 + 4 = 654. Теперь понятнее?

Comment: я в чем-то неправ?

Comment: Причем здесь не прав? Я говорю я хочу разобраться я начинающий программер, а ты кичишься тем, что соображаешь и в завуалированной форме назвал меня тупым. Короче спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 2):

Код C++, [взят с форума](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread103665.html), который был найден в поисковике за минуту:

```
bool palindrom( char * str) { 
    int left_index = 0;
    int right_index = strlen(str)-1;

    while( left_index < right_index ) 
        if( str[left_index++]!= str[right_index--]) 
            return false;

    return true;
};
```

**Добавлено:**

вот функция:

```
long Perevert(long x)
{
   long y = 0;
   while(x)
   {
       y = y*10 + x%10;
       x /= 10;
   }
   return y;
}
```

и вот еще:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
       std::string cBuf;
       std::cin >> cBuf;
       int k = cBuf.length();
       while(k-- > 0)  std::cout << cBuf[k];
       std::cout << std :: endl;
       system("pause");
}
```

Тоже [взято с форума](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread343827.html), там еще пару вариантов )

Comment: он хочет кое-чего другого

Comment: @DreamChild что он хочет? )))
а, кажется понял, это то, чтобы в одну строку записать, чтобы сразу ответ записать?

Comment: Я написал чего хочу в вопросе =)))

Comment: ему нужно определить число, получаемое из исходного путем записи исходного "задом наперед". 123 => 321, 836 => 638 и тд. Судя по всему, очередная лабораторная

Comment: То есть вводишь трехзначное число, а прога должна это число перевернуть. 123 => 321

Comment: ну да, с новым заголовком все встало на свои места )

Comment: Прально я ж учусь, препод еще не прикатил домой пытаюсь сам разобраться чо делать надо.

Comment: обновил ответ )

да простят меня за готовые функции

Comment: Благодарю милейший =)